# Kendo Mobile Q3 2012 - Font Icons Display as Squares in Android v4+

Tags: css, listview, kendo-ui

When I force platform "ios" in Kendo UI Mobile, none of the default font-icons display properly in Android v4+ (instead, I just see solid squares using the correct respective CSS color property). What's interesting is that the icons do display properly in Android v2.3.x. Any workaround known as of yet? I have seen CSS workarounds for similar scenarios, however, they are all based prior to the new font icon rendering method.

I am using Kendo UI Mobile Q3 2012 release, v2012.3.1114, and am using the `data-icon="globe"` attribute on my list tags within a Kendo UI Mobile ListView.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have asked the same question before, and I got an answer from Kendo.

Add this style:

```
 .km-root .km-on-android .km-view span.km-icon
{
    background: none;
}

.km-root .km-pane.km-pane.km-on-android .km-view span.km-icon:after
{
    background: none;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: inherit;
}
```